# Calling one variable of a class in another class?

Tags: java

Hi I am new to the java programming. I have a instance variable in a class which I should call to another class.It should not be static as per the requirements.The code given below## `

```
public class Card {

    private String no;
    private String text;
    public Vector totalCards = new Vector();

    public String getNo() {
        totalCards.addElement(no);
        return no;
    }

    public void setNo(String no) {
        this.no = no;
    }

    public String getText() {
        totalCards.addElement(text);
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

I need  to pass this  "totalCards" vector in another class without making it as a static.How can I pass this value.Can anybody help me. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Does a method in another class need to accept a "Vector" as an argument? Please be more clear about what it is you need to do.

Comment: If this is homework you should tag it as such, but as a quick homework-like answer, you created setters and getters for your other two variables, why not just do the same for totalCards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear exactly what your issue is, but you first need to have an instance of Card.  The totalCards Vector will then live in that Card object.

```
Card myCards = new Card();
```

Now the object that has access to myCards can access the Vector with:

```
myCards.totalCards
```

However, it's considered a better practice by many to make totalCards private and make a getter for it:

```
myCards.getTotalCards();
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the variable "totalCards" is public, it can be directly accessed via an instance of Card.

Answer (score 1):

You simply write in your class:

```
public class AnotherClass 
{
  public Class obj1 = new Class();


public String getNo() 
{
    Vector v1 = obj1.totalCards;
    return v1; //or what do you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass totalCards reference to other class because is public. Tell us more about client class. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Card {
    private String no;
    private String text;
    /* initializing totalCards here is bad, why are you doing this here?  If each
       card has a list of totalCards, consider doing this in the constructor of a
       Card */
    private Vector<Card> totalCards = new Vector();

    public String getNo() {
        //getters should not have side effects like addElement...
        totalCards.addElement(no);
        return no;         
    }

    public Vector<Card> getCards() { 
        return totalCards;
    }

    public void setNo(String no) {
        this.no = no;
    }

    public String getText() {
        //getters should not have side effects like addElement...
        totalCards.addElement(text);
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other class needs to have an instance of `Card`. For example by creating a new instance:

```
public class TheOtherClass {
    private Card myCard = new Card();

    public void doSomething() {
        myCard.totalCards.doAnotherThing();
    }
}
```

By the way: It's considered as bad style to access properties of other classes directly - try to use setters and getters:

```
public class Card {
    private Vector<Card> totalCards = new Vector();
    public void getTotalCards() {
        return totalCards;
    }
}
```